# scala is using akka shipped with binary distribution instead of sbt 's one

Tags: scala, sbt, akka

I have a project that uses akka in version 2.11_2.5.21 which is assembly in my fat jar.

I have download the scala binary 2.11.12 and it is shipped with a `lib/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.16.jar` (next to `bin/scala`)

When I run my project : `scala  -cp target/scala-2.11/project-assembly-2.4.0.jar foo.MyClass` I get

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: akka.actor.OneForOneStrategy.withMaxNrOfRetries(I)Lakka/actor/OneForOneStrategy;
```

If i remove `lib/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.16.jar` in my scala directory it works.

Of course it  also works with sbt run as sbt used its own scala version.

Why does scala binary use its own akka version instead of the one shipped in the fat jar?

Comment: Why would **Scala** include **Akka** at all? Also, why are you running an assembly **JAR** with **Scala** the idea of an assembly **JAR** is to be able to execute it with just **Java**.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming by "Scala binary" you are referring to the decompressed structure of say https://downloads.lightbend.com/scala/2.11.12/scala-2.11.12.tgz

```
➜  scala-2.11.12 tree -L 2
.
├── bin
│   ├── fsc
│   ├── fsc.bat
│   ├── scala
│   ├── scala.bat
│   ├── scalac
│   ├── scalac.bat
│   ├── scaladoc
│   ├── scaladoc.bat
│   ├── scalap
│   └── scalap.bat
├── doc
│   ├── LICENSE.md
│   ├── License.rtf
│   ├── README
│   ├── licenses
│   └── tools
├── lib
│   ├── akka-actor_2.11-2.3.16.jar
│   ├── config-1.2.1.jar
│   ├── jline-2.14.3.jar
│   ├── scala-actors-2.11.0.jar
│   ├── scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar
│   ├── scala-compiler.jar
│   ├── scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar
│   ├── scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.12-1.0.2.jar
│   ├── scala-library.jar
│   ├── scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.4.jar
│   ├── scala-reflect.jar
│   ├── scala-swing_2.11-1.0.2.jar
│   ├── scala-xml_2.11-1.0.5.jar
│   └── scalap-2.11.12.jar
└── man
    └── man1
```

then everything inside `lib/` will take precedence over what you specify with `-cp`. To see this analyse the following snippet of `bin/scala` runner script

```
execCommand \
  "${JAVACMD:=java}" \
  $JAVA_OPTS \
  "${java_args[@]}" \
  "${classpath_args[@]}" \
  -Dscala.home="$SCALA_HOME" \
  $OVERRIDE_USEJAVACP \
  "$EMACS_OPT" \
  $WINDOWS_OPT \
   scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner  "$@"
```

Note that `"${classpath_args[@]}"` which holds jars from `lib` precedes the last `"$@"` which holds your arguments such as `-cp`. Finally JVM will pick the **first** matching class it finds on the classpath which in your case will be the one from `lib/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.16.jar`. For example

```
scala -cp target/scala-2.11/project-assembly-2.4.0.jar
```

would expand to something like

```
java -Xbootclasspath/a:/scala-2.11.12/lib/akka-actor_2.11-2.3.16.jar ... scala.tools.nsc.MainGenericRunner -cp target/scala-2.11/project-assembly-2.4.0.jar
```

hence `Xbootclasspath` would take precedence over `-cp`.